# Notification Intent - How to resume the activity in a notification without resetting?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, timer, android-notifications

I am making a timer app.. So that when uses clicks on the start button the notification shows up and when the user clicks on the notification the timer should be resuming rather it shows a ***new activity*** which starts again from the first.

I have tried `TaskStackbuilder` still the problem prevails.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);

PendingIntent res = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer)
            .setContentTitle("Productivity Timer")
            .setContentText("Your Timer is Running")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROGRESS)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(res)
            .build();

notificationManager.notify(1,not);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code. please review the same and let me know if you are still getting any query.

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


Notification not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_timer)
        .setContentTitle("Productivity Timer")
        .setContentText("Your Timer is Running")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROGRESS)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();
     notificationManager.notify(1,not);
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please explain how the changes you made will solve the problem.

Comment: Please compare your code with my code.if the solution of your problem is this then you can get an idea about that.

Comment: Mainly, I have changed pending intent initialization and removed taskstackbuilder.according to me, that was creating a problem.

Comment: it isn't my code. As a member of Stack Overflow, I am making a suggestion to improve the quality of your answer so that it will be useful for future visitors.

Comment: '@PoojaShukla Thank you so much! It Woked!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you. i appreciate but if my answer solves someone's problem then maybe I have answered properly.

Comment: It will be even more helpful if you actually explain how and why it works.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sure, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to resume activity

**Manifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Also you can use this whenever you need to bring activity to front

```
private void bringAppFront() {
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```